# Datatable select from textbox

Tags: c#, .net

I have a datatable like this:

```
REFERENCE   DESCRIPTION
AAAA1       AAAA1 DESCRIPTION
AAAA2       AAAA2 DESCRIPTION
AAAA3       AAAA3 DESCRIPTION
AAAA4       AAAA4 DESCRIPTION
```

If I make the selection like this it works fine.

```
DataRow[] row = table.Select("REFERENCE = 'AAAA1'");
```

but if I do it like this:

```
string reference = tbRef.Text;
DataRow[] row = table.Select("REFERENCE = '{0}'", reference);
```

I get an exception: **System.IndexOutOfRangeException**

Comment: `table.Select($"REFERENCE = '{reference}'")` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select?view=net-5.0#System_Data_DataTable_Select_System_String_System_String_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter of `Select` is a *sort* parameter

[DataTable.Select(String, String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.select?view=net-5.0#System_Data_DataTable_Select_System_String_System_String_)

> **Parameters**
>
> - filterExpression `String` : The criteria to use to filter the rows. For examples on how to filter
>   rows, see DataView RowFilter Syntax [C#].
> - sort `String` : **A string specifying the column and sort direction**.

Likely you just want [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

> The $ special character identifies a string literal as an interpolated
> string. An interpolated string is a string literal that might contain
> interpolation expressions. When an interpolated string is resolved to
> a result string, items with interpolation expressions are replaced by
> the string representations of the expression results. This feature is
> available starting with C# 6.

```
string reference = tbRef.Text
table.Select($"REFERENCE = '{reference}'")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `DataRow.Select` method doesn't directly support numeric tokens for string formatting. You need to feed it a ready-made string (which could have been pre-created using such a method).

You can either:

1. use string interpolation:

   ```
   DataRow[] row = table.Select($"REFERENCE = '{reference}'");
   ```

OR

2. wrap your existing code in a `String.Format` call:

   ```
   DataRow[] row = table.Select(String.Format("REFERENCE = '{0}'", reference));
   ```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/9puU6w